# How to Use Cufon Replacement In IE Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2010

I want to Replace Cufon text in Div but its not proper working in IE Browser
i.e : My Div ID is "WelcomeTextDiv" and in This textcontent is afterlife|pramoter@gmail.com 
      and that time i was alter this content usign jquery which is below

```
$('#WelcomeTextDiv').find("cufon").attr('alt', "Pramotor");
```

so its output in Firefox is Pramotor

But In IE Browser

```
Pramotorafterlife|pramoter@gmail.com
```

means execute alter but also remain Login Content..Any other Way to Solve This..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use embedded fonts. May that will help you ;)
 http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

This method is faster and does not require any javascript to use your special fonts ;)